# Can Mathematica help to rearrange an equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation which I want to rearrange so one variable is on the left side by itself.

Normally, I would do this with basic algebra and identities.

However, is it possible to use Mathematica to do this for me, automatically?

Comment: Hello Gravitas, and welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an extremely general question, but usually, yes.
The commonly used functions used are [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) and [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html):

```
Reduce[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, a]
```

> ```
> x != 0 && a == (-1 - x^2)/x
> ```

The documentation pages linked above contain many examples.  Please read these, and if necessary narrow your question to a specific difficulty or problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was asked, `AddSides` etc `*Sides` have been added to Mathematica for the purpose.

`Simplify` makes some things automatically.